# User function and array

Tags: python, arrays

This is my first day learning python. I'm trying to make a user function. The function is passed an array, called b. When I write the code without passing the array, it works.

```
b = [5, 32, 19, 84, 3, 3]

if len(a) == 5:
    a4 = a[4]
else: a4 = 0

b3 = a[3]
b2 = a[2]
b1 = a[1]
b0 = a[0]

#Calculation with b0 b1 b2...
```

However, when I attempt to make a function it does not.

```
def PassFunction(b):    
    if len(a) == 5:
        a4 = a[4]
    else: a4 = 0

    b3 = a[3]
    b2 = a[2]
    b1 = a[1]
    b0 = a[0]

#Calculation with b0 b1 b2...
```

The main function that I am using this function in is:

```
def main():

b = [1,2,3,4]

number = PassFunction(b)
print(number)
```

The error I get is:

```
b3 = a[3]
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Changing b3 to a3 produced the same error:

```
a3 = a[3]
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Adding a return statement to the end of the PassFunction fixed the error.

I know there must be a simple fix for this, but I cannot find it. If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What _exactly_ does not work? Do you get an error message? If so, paste it into your post. What is `a` in the first example? How is it defined?

Comment: What is `a` over here?

Comment: You *created* the function, but no where do you actually *use*, or call, that function, yet. Maybe you need to call the function as `PassFunction(b)` *outside* of the function itself.

Comment: what is your a and where you call the function?

Comment: What part of `NameError: name 'a' is not defined` is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

You have `b` as a parameter in your function but you're referring to `a` (which is not defined in that scope).
Just use `b` instead of `a` in the body of your function.
Oh and I assume there's some indentation wrong for the `main` function, maybe pasting the code? That `main` is empty...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def PassFunction(a):    
    if len(a) == 5:
        a4 = a[4]
    else: a4 = 0

    b3 = a[3]
    b2 = a[2]
    b1 = a[1]
    b0 = a[0]

#Calculation with b0 b1 b2...
```

You used the wrong parameter name. Instead of `b` use `a`

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you haven't declared  the variable a before you assigned it in `a4 = a[4]`, so you have to declare a as a list at the start:

```
a = [w,r,i,t,e, ,y,o,u,r, ,i,t,e,m,s, ,h,e,r,e]
```

I hope I've helped!